# VBA Input Function shows Run time error, type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a input box, and put the input into corresponding cells. But it show type mismatch.

```
Sub Profit_Projection()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim psales As Integer
    Dim msg1 As String
    
    psales = InputBox("Please enter the predicted growth of sales next month in decimal form.", "Sales Growth", 1)    
       
    If StrPtr(psales) = 0 Then
      MsgBox "You clicked Cancel button"
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf psales = "" Then
        MsgBox "You didnt enter input"
      Exit Sub
    Else
        Val (psales)
        Range("B5") = psales * 100
         If Range("B5").IsNumeric = False Then
          msg1 = "The number inputted is is not integer. Please try again in decimal form."
          MsgBox msg1, vbOKOnly, "Incorrect Input"
        End If
    End If
    
    
End Sub
```

Comment: you have to declare psales as `variant`

Answer (score 2):

Your main problem is that `InputBox` returns a String (see the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/inputbox-function)), but you assign it to a numeric variable.

If the user enters some non-numeric data, you will get the type mismatch already at the `psales = InputBox` - statement.

If the user enters a numeric value, VBA will convert it into a number. But then you get a a type mismatch for the statement `psales = ""` because you cannot compare a number and a string (even if it is an empty string).

So you should assign the result of the `InputBox` first to a String variable and then check step by step if the entered value was okay:

```
Sub Profit_Projection()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim psales As Integer
    Dim answer
    Dim msg1 As String
    
    answer = InputBox("Please enter the predicted growth of sales next month in decimal form.", "Sales Growth", 1)
    If StrPtr(answer) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "You clicked Cancel button"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Trim(answer) = "" Then
        MsgBox "You didnt enter anything"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Not IsNumeric(answer) Then
        MsgBox "You didnt enter a number"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If CInt(answer) <> Val(answer) Then
        MsgBox "You didnt enter an integer "
        Exit Sub
    End If
   
    psales = Val(answer)
    ActiveSheet.Range("B5") = psales * 100
End Sub
```

Comment: @KostasK. Sure, good catch, corrected.